# Send UDP datagrams to multiple interfaces with multicast address

Tags: c, windows, sockets, routes, multicast

I have a Windows 11 machine that has two network interfaces:

1. `192.168.1.16/24` (Wi-Fi: physical Ethernet connected to external router)
2. `172.22.112.1/20` (vEthernet (Default Switch): internal virtual switch from Hyper-V)

I am writing an application that should send multicast messages via both interfaces.

Ideally I would like to send the data only once from the application and the data would end up on both interfaces without configuring Windows :) :

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, ...)
bind(s, INADDR_ANY,...)
sendto(s, buf, ..., 239.255.0.1, ...)
```

The messages arrives unfortunately only on the Wi-Fi interface. This interface is determined by the routing table, I guess.

```
PS>netstat -rn
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.16     50
...
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.22.112.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.16    306
...
```

In this case it goes only to interface 192.168.1.16 because the metric is the minimum of the matching route. This also happens if both interfaces have joined the multicast group.

```
PS> netsh int ip show joins
Interface 1: Wi-Fi

Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
...
0                    1  Yes   239.255.0.1
0                    3  Yes   239.255.255.250
...
Interface 2: vEthernet (Default Switch)

Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
...
0                    1  Yes   239.255.0.1
0                    4  Yes   239.255.255.250
```

One solution I found, is to send the packet twice like so:

```
setsockopt (socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, 192.168.1.16, ...)
sendto(s, buf, ..., 239.255.0.1, ...)
setsockopt (socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, 172.22.112.1, ...)
sendto(s, buf, ..., 239.255.0.1, ...)
```

Is there a way to achieve the sending of the multicast message via all interfaces without the `setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_IF` loop? Maybe I missed some socket options?

Or if not possible in code, is there a way to configure Windows to forward the packets to all interfaces?

Originally I thought multicast would go to all joining interfaces, is Windows handling this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets will only ever go out one interface, whether they are unicast, multicast, or broadcast.

The correct way to handle this is as you've discovered, namely to set the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` option on the socket before sending the packet.

Comment: Thanks! That packets go out on one interface, is that always like that? Can Windows not act like a router with some configuration?